# Capture Paste Content in Ember 2.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, ember.js, clipboarddata

I have an Ember App (Ember 2.6) and I am trying to capture paste data before it is pasted into a input component. I have tried registering a custom event in my Ember App following the docs.

https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.Application/properties/customEvents?anchor=customEvents&show=inherited%2Cprotected%2Cprivate%2Cdeprecated

Then in my component...

```
paste: function(event) {
    console.log(event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))
}
```

This returns an empty string when pasting "foo".

I also tried this with jquery...

```
$('.table').on('paste',function(event) {
  console.log(event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))
}
```

This also returns an empty string.

I have read other stack overflow answers surrounding this issue and haven't found a solution that works for me. I have tried...

```
event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
window.clipboardData..getData('text/plain')
```

For getData() I have also tried...

```
'text', and 'Text'
```

What do I do?

Comment: FYI the doc entry for customEvents is the same for 2.6 as 2.15

Answer (score 1):

Your mileage may vary, but I am capturing a paste event like this:

```
if (event.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
  items = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text').split('\r');
} else {
  items = window.clipboardData.getData('Text').split('\r');
}
```

The `split` is assuming a multi-line paste (so each line is a different item) for my use case, but it should work the same if you don't have multiple lines in the paste.